# Variance of Poisson distributed variables $\leq1$

Tags: probability, statistics, poisson-distribution, variance

If $Z_n$ is the number of sample observations of $X\leq1$ where $X \sim \text{Poisson}(\mu)$, then what is $\text{Var}(\frac{Z_n}{n}$)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints:

- $\text{Var}(Z_n/n) = \frac{1}{n^2} \text{Var}(Z_n)$
- $Z_n$ can be written as $I_1 + I_2 + \cdots + I_n$ where $I_j$ is a random variable that equals $1$ if $X_j \le 1$, and equals $0$ otherwise.
- If $I_1, \ldots, I_n$ are independent then $\text{Var}(I_1 + \cdots + I_n) = \text{Var}(I_1) + \cdots + \text{Var}(I_n)$.

Comment: Very elegant! If I understand it correctly, $I$ is a Bernoulli variable with $p = P[X\leq1]$. p follows from POI and is equal to $e^{-\mu}(1+\mu)$. $Var(I)$ can be found in any probability book ($=p(1-p)$). Final answer would be $\frac{1}{n}p(1-p)$